# Number of $n$ lettered words made out of $n$ A's and $n$ B's with specified conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

> Number of $n$ lettered words made out of $n$ **A**'s and $n$ **B**'s such that the number of **A**'s from the left is at all times greater than the number of **B**'s from the left. String needs to contain both letters $A$ and $B$.

From my understanding there has to be a minimum value for $n$ which goes at three and includes both **A** and **B** as 3:
$$AAB$$

For $n$ with a value of 4:
$$AAAB$$
$$AABA$$

For $n$ with value 5:
$$AAAAB$$
$$AAABA$$
$$AABAA$$
$$AAABB$$
$$AABAB$$

And so on...

From this we know that the minimum value of **A** in a string of $n$ letters is $\frac{(n+1)}{2}$ and a max value of **B** is $\frac{(n-1)}{2}$ for an odd integer $n$. A min value of A is $\frac{(n+2)}{2}$ and a max value of $\frac{(n-2)}{2}$ for an even integer $n$. And the string has to start with two **A**'s.

.....

I am having trouble approaching the problem. Any hints appreciated(algebraic hints preferred).

**Edit**:

1. I seemed to have misunderstood the condition specified to be followed in chunks of $A$ and $B$. The conditions do not apply in chunks.
2. The string has to include both letters $A$ and $B$.
3. The statement "$n$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s" is trivial and holds not value. Only the fact that both $A$ and $B$ have to be included in the string is necessary.

Comment: For $n = 5$, you omitted the case $AABAB$.

Comment: The number of $A$s always exceeds the number of $B$s in the sequence $AABAB$: $(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2)$.

Comment: Also, it is not clear why you are excluding sequences with all $A$s.

Comment: I am sorry I thought the conditions follow in chunks. You are right, I will edit it.

Comment: The string of letters has to include both letters, hence a string of all $A$'s isn't allowed.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem right. Either the string is of length $n$ or you are interested in strings of lengths $2n$ with $n$ $A$ letters and $n$ $B$ letters. From your post, it seems that you mean a string of length $n$ comprised of $A$ and $B$'s.

Comment: The condition does not say that both $A$s and $B$s must be present, just that the number of $A$s from the left is at all times greater than the number of $B$s.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: "String needs to contain both letters A and B." in the problem statement

Comment: @trueblueanil  It was not in the original problem statement.  Check the edit history.

Comment: See my edited answer, where googling the sequence of generated numbers finds https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html which gives you details about the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @N.F. Taussig: Oh !

Comment: @ayan3095: Your problem statement says *"n A's and n B's"* which normally means exactly *n* of each, then you have edited to write "string needs to contain both letters A and B"  Can you clarify *exactly* what you have in mind ?

Comment: @true blue anil the statement "$n$ $A$'s and $n$ $B$'s" is trivial and holds not meaning. Just the fact that the string is of n letters is important and that both $A$ and $B$ must be included is important.

Comment: In case it's still of any interest, I asked about (a slight generalization of) this question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416289/ where it was pointed out that it's already been exhaustively studied as "Dyck paths", e.g., https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gabriella_Baracchini_final_paper.pdf and about a million other google hits. Your question's simply a re-worded version of what's formally the same thing. So you can check out "Dyck paths" for rigorous derivations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to shorten my preceding answer, and to explicitly give you the mathematical expression, for words of length $n$ the answer is just the binomial coefficient
$$\left(n-1 \atop \lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor\right)$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is just the floor function, or in this case just integer division truncating the fractional part. (And I added that to my copy of the preceding answer's code, and it indeed checks. I can re-post that code if you actually want it for anything.)

**Edit --**   Oops, I hadn't noticed @ayan3095's *Edit* to his question, where he explicitly adds the constraint *"2.The string has to include both letters A and B."*    So I added that constraint to the code in the preceding answer, and the new numerically-generated results are simply one less than they were without the constraint.

So the new-and-improved (but very little changed) mathematical expression is that for words of length $n$ the answer is
$$\left(n-1 \atop \lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor\right) - 1$$

By the way, as posted in the preceding answer, this is just (an alternative definition of) the central binomial coefficient, as discussed in detail at, e.g.,
    https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html 
    https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c178.htm 
And note that I never rigorously set up @ayan3095's problem and derived this solution. Instead, I just programmed the problem, generating a sequence of answers for $n=1,2,\ldots,20$ and then just googled that sequence of numbers, immediately finding the above links. Kind of like googling the answer to find the question, or something like that. So is this the new *"new math"*??? **:)**

In any case, this still leaves the issue of rigorously deriving the above answer *ab initio* from @ayan3095's question, which I have no idea how to approach. Maybe somebody else might care to take a stab at that.

Comment: I am having trouble: $\binom{n-1}{\lfloor {\frac{n-1}{2}}\rfloor}$ give value 2 for $n$=3. But for $n$=3 there exists only $AAB$ and for value 4 there exists only $AAAB$, $AABA$.

Comment: @ayan3095 Oops... I hadn't noticed your edit "the string has to include both letters A and B". I changed my code to include that constraint so we could numerically generate the answers. And guess what?... in every case it reduces the answer by exactly $1$. Does that make sense to you??? I'm not immediately seeing why it should behave that way, but I re-checked the code, and it's apparently right. So just subtract $1$ from that binomial coefficient. And now you're getting the right answers. Right??? And I'm editing my answer to reflect this comment.

Comment: It is reduced by exactly one because there is only one string of length $n$ that contains all A's and no B's

Comment: Yes you are right. But the $n-1$ in the floor function seems trivial. It can be left at the floor of just $\frac{n}{2}$. Right??

Comment: @DanielMathias **Doh!!!** Thanks for pointing out that obvious explanation. Don't know how I overlooked it. But I managed to:)

Comment: @ayan3095 No, obviously not, I don't think, e.g., for $n=4$ you'd get $n/2=2$ whereas $(n-1)/2=1$ (with the usual integer truncation). But see those links I posted in the preceding answer for lots of detailed discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting yet another answer because I got interested in @ayan3095's problem, generalized it, and found some interesting (at least to me) results, that might be worth discussing.

Rather than just strings of length $n$ consisting of **A,B**, as originally asked by @ayan3095, consider strings consisting of **A,B,C,...**. Or, for programming purposes, strings of length $n$ in base $b$ (so $b^n$ of them). And a rather simple generalization of the program posted in my original answer accommodates this problem generalization.

And I found the results interesting because googling them came up with entirely different mathematical functions for each base $b$. If we ignore @ayan3095's constraint   *2.The string has to include both letters A and B*   (it just reduces all answers by $1$), then for base $b=2$ and various $n$ we've already found the original answer (an alternate form of the centarl binomial coefficient)
$$f(b=2,n) = \left(n-1 \atop \lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor\right)$$
And now for $b=3$ the program generates answers...

```
bash-5.1$ ./prefmax 1 12 3 0
n= 1, nwords=       3,  nmax=     1
n= 2, nwords=       9,  nmax=     1
n= 3, nwords=      27,  nmax=     3
n= 4, nwords=      81,  nmax=     5
n= 5, nwords=     243,  nmax=    15
n= 6, nwords=     729,  nmax=    29
n= 7, nwords=    2187,  nmax=    87
n= 8, nwords=    6561,  nmax=   181
n= 9, nwords=   19683,  nmax=   543
n=10, nwords=   59049,  nmax=  1181
n=11, nwords=  177147,  nmax=  3543
n=12, nwords=  531441,  nmax=  7941
```

And guess what? See
    https://oeis.org/A126087 
which generates exactly our sequence, but bears no relation whatsoever (not that I can see, anyway) to our $b=2$ case giving the central binomial coefficient above.

And for $b=4$ the program gives...

```
bash-5.1$ ./prefmax 1 12 4 0
n= 1, nwords=       4,  nmax=     1
n= 2, nwords=      16,  nmax=     1
n= 3, nwords=      64,  nmax=     4
n= 4, nwords=     256,  nmax=     7
n= 5, nwords=    1024,  nmax=    28
n= 6, nwords=    4096,  nmax=    58
n= 7, nwords=   16384,  nmax=   232
n= 8, nwords=   65536,  nmax=   523
n= 9, nwords=  262144,  nmax=  2092
n=10, nwords= 1048576,  nmax=  4966
n=11, nwords= 4194304,  nmax= 19864
n=12, nwords=16777216,  nmax= 48838
```

And guess what again? See 
    https://oeis.org/A128386/b128386.txt 
for exactly our sequence, but this time without explanation how they derived it.

So, the overall result is that we have our $f(b,n)$, generated in exactly one numerical way, but identified with apparently entirely unrelated mathematical functions for $b=2,3,4$. And for $b=5$ I couldn't google anything. So perhaps we're looking at some new more general function, for which the already-known $b=2,3,4$ functions are just special cases. Anyway, that's the conjecture I'm suggesting might be worth investigating further.

Answer (score 0):

**>>E d i t and Answer<< ---** Okay, googling the numerically-generated sequence of numbers generated below gets us to
   
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html 
where about halfway down the page you'll find
    "A less common alternative definition of the nth central binomial coefficient is...
    ...of which "the first few values are 1, 2, 3, 6, 10, 20, 35, 70, 126, 252, ..."
So I daresay that's your answer. Or see
   
https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c178.htm 
for a similar discussion.

More of an extended comment than an answer:
if we replace A and B by 0 and 1, we're talking about binary strings,
and that's easily programmed. For strings of length $n$,
all we have to do is consider the 0,1-binary representation of every number
$i:0\le i\lt 2^n$. And the results for $n=1\ldots20$ are

```
n= 1,  nwords=       2,  n0max=     1,  n1max=     1
n= 2,  nwords=       4,  n0max=     1,  n1max=     1
n= 3,  nwords=       8,  n0max=     2,  n1max=     2
n= 4,  nwords=      16,  n0max=     3,  n1max=     3
n= 5,  nwords=      32,  n0max=     6,  n1max=     6
n= 6,  nwords=      64,  n0max=    10,  n1max=    10
n= 7,  nwords=     128,  n0max=    20,  n1max=    20
n= 8,  nwords=     256,  n0max=    35,  n1max=    35
n= 9,  nwords=     512,  n0max=    70,  n1max=    70
n=10,  nwords=    1024,  n0max=   126,  n1max=   126
n=11,  nwords=    2048,  n0max=   252,  n1max=   252
n=12,  nwords=    4096,  n0max=   462,  n1max=   462
n=13,  nwords=    8192,  n0max=   924,  n1max=   924
n=14,  nwords=   16384,  n0max=  1716,  n1max=  1716
n=15,  nwords=   32768,  n0max=  3432,  n1max=  3432
n=16,  nwords=   65536,  n0max=  6435,  n1max=  6435
n=17,  nwords=  131072,  n0max= 12870,  n1max= 12870
n=18,  nwords=  262144,  n0max= 24310,  n1max= 24310
n=19,  nwords=  524288,  n0max= 48620,  n1max= 48620
n=20,  nwords= 1048576,  n0max= 92378,  n1max= 92378
```

n0max is the number of times 0's are greater, and just as a check
it also prints the number of times 1's are greater.
Silly little C program is below...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  int n1 = ( argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 1 ),
      n2 = ( argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 10 );
  int  n = n1;
  int ipow(), nwords=0, iword=0,
      isprefmax(char*,char), n0max=0, n1max=0;
  char *itoa();
  for ( n=n1; n<=n2; n++ ) {
    nwords = ipow(2,n);
    n0max = n1max = 0;
    for ( iword=0; iword<nwords; iword++ ) {
      char *aword = itoa(iword,2,n);
      if ( isprefmax(aword,'0') ) n0max++;
      if ( isprefmax(aword,'1') ) n1max++; }
    printf("n=%2d,  nwords=%8d,  n0max=%6d,  n1max=%6d\n",
    n,nwords,n0max,n1max); }
  exit(0); }

int  isprefmax ( char *a, char c ) {
  int i=0, nc=0, nother=0;  int ismax=0;
  if ( a == NULL ) goto end_of_job;
  while ( a[i] != '\000' ) {
    if ( a[i] == c ) nc++; else nother++;
    if ( nother >= nc ) goto end_of_job;
    i++; }
  ismax = 1;
  end_of_job: return ( ismax ); }

int ipow ( int base, int exp ) {
  int basetoexp = 1;
  while ( 1 ) {
    if ( exp&1 ) basetoexp *= base;
    exp >>= 1;
    if ( !exp ) break;
    base *= base; }
  return ( basetoexp ); }

char *itoa ( int i, int base, int len ) {
  static char a[99], digits[99] = /* up to base 65 */
      "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz#$*";
  int n=0, j=0,k=0;
  while ( 1 ) {
    a[n++] = digits[i%base];
    if ( (i/=base) < 1 ) break; }
  a[n] = '\000';
  for ( k=n-1,j=0; k>j; k--,j++ ) {
    char ak=a[k]; a[k]=a[j]; a[j]=ak; }
  if ( n < len ) {
    memmove(a+(len-n),a,n);
    memset(a,'0',(len-n)); }
  return ( a ); }
```

Comment: You mention binary representation, but use strings instead of bits. See [my code](https://pastebin.com/w6sjAEBN) for comparison, which also includes a recursive routine.

Comment: @DanielMathias Oh, yeah, it makes no difference to the ultimate answers, and I already had that itoa() routine lying around for other purposes (as well as ipow()). So I just implemented what was easiest. But, yeah, recursive is nice.